# Insertar datos de una tabla en otra SQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo una BBDD en MySQL para un concesionario de coches. Existen 3 tipos de usuarios: A,C y P. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, que cuando se inserta un nuevo dato en la tabla usuarios con tipo "P", se inserte también en la tabla proveedores.

Es decir, que cuando añado un usuario de tipo proveedor, se cree también un nuevo elemento en la tabla proveedor. En proveedor el ProveedorID se corresponde con UsuarioID. No se cómo hacer el trigger para conseguirlo.

Dejo una foto de la BBDD por si sirve de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_to_proveedores
AFTER INSERT
ON usuariosFOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE vUser int(10) unsigned;
SELECT UsuarioID INTO vUser;
INSERT INTO proveedor(ProveedorID) VALUES(vUser);
END;
```

También dejo el código para crear la base de datos.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 26-04-2018 a las 00:06:24
-- Versión del servidor: 5.7.21-log
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `concesionarioguerra`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `administrador`
--

CREATE TABLE `administrador` (
  `AdministradorID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `administrador`
--

INSERT INTO `administrador` (`AdministradorID`) VALUES
(0000000001);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `concesionario`
--

CREATE TABLE `concesionario` (
  `ConcesionarioID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `concesionario`
--

INSERT INTO `concesionario` (`ConcesionarioID`) VALUES
(0000000003);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `pedidos`
--

CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `ConcesionarioID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `ProductoID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `ProveedorID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Confirmacion` char(1) DEFAULT 'N'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pedidos`
--

INSERT INTO `pedidos` (`ConcesionarioID`, `ProductoID`, `ProveedorID`, `Fecha`, `Confirmacion`) VALUES
(0000000003, 0000000001, 0000000002, '2018-04-25', 'N');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `productos`
--

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `ProductoID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `ProveedorID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precio` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stock` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StockSeguridad` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Color` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `productos`
--

INSERT INTO `productos` (`ProductoID`, `ProveedorID`, `Nombre`, `Precio`, `Stock`, `StockSeguridad`, `Color`) VALUES
(0000000001, 0000000002, 'Coche1', '1000.00', 50, 5, 'Azul'),
(0000000002, 0000000002, 'Coche2', '2000.00', 40, 4, 'Rojo');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `proveedor`
--

CREATE TABLE `proveedor` (
  `ProveedorID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `proveedor`
--

INSERT INTO `proveedor` (`ProveedorID`) VALUES
(0000000002);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `UsuarioID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `DNI` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Nick` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `NombreCompleto` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telefono` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CuentaBancaria` char(24) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`, `DNI`, `Nick`, `Email`, `Password`, `Tipo`, `NombreCompleto`, `Telefono`, `CuentaBancaria`) VALUES
(0000000001, '45689217Q', 'ppascr00', 'ppascr00@gmail.es', '123', 'A', 'Pedro José Pascual Ruano', '123456789', '1852 9993 67 1716732024'),
(0000000002, '45689218Z', 'cortig00', 'ccortig00@gmail.es', '123', 'P', 'César Ortigueira García', '123456789', '0689 5802 60 1374177426'),
(0000000003, '45689219H', 'agutiv00', 'agutiv00@gmail.es', '123', 'C', 'Álvaro Gutiérrez Fernández', '123456789', '6480 0807 45 5785356090');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `administrador`
--
ALTER TABLE `administrador`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AdministradorID`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `concesionario`
--
ALTER TABLE `concesionario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ConcesionarioID`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `pedidos`
--
ALTER TABLE `pedidos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ConcesionarioID`,`ProductoID`,`ProveedorID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_concesionario_has_productos_concesionario1_idx` (`ConcesionarioID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_Pedidos_productos1_idx` (`ProductoID`,`ProveedorID`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `productos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProductoID`,`ProveedorID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ProductoID_UNIQUE` (`ProductoID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_productos_proveedor1_idx` (`ProveedorID`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `proveedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `proveedor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProveedorID`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`UsuarioID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UsuarioID_UNIQUE` (`UsuarioID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `DNI_UNIQUE` (`DNI`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Nick_UNIQUE` (`Nick`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `productos`
  MODIFY `ProductoID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `UsuarioID` int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `administrador`
--
ALTER TABLE `administrador`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_administrador_usuarios1` FOREIGN KEY (`AdministradorID`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `concesionario`
--
ALTER TABLE `concesionario`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_concesionario_usuarios1` FOREIGN KEY (`ConcesionarioID`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `pedidos`
--
ALTER TABLE `pedidos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Pedidos_productos1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductoID`,`ProveedorID`) REFERENCES `productos` (`ProductoID`, `ProveedorID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_concesionario_has_productos_concesionario1` FOREIGN KEY (`ConcesionarioID`) REFERENCES `concesionario` (`ConcesionarioID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `productos`
--
ALTER TABLE `productos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_productos_proveedor1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProveedorID`) REFERENCES `proveedor` (`ProveedorID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `proveedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `proveedor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_proveedor_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`ProveedorID`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Te dejo el link donde muestra como trabajar un trigger after insert en mysql
[https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)

Comment: agrega tu codigo de trigger lo que llevas hecho

Comment: Ya está, entre la foto y el codigo de la bbdd

Comment: Hola, lo que tienes que saber es que los datos del nuevo registro los obtienes con NEW.{nombre_campo}. Sería NEW.UsuarioID en éste caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido la solución. Es tan sencillo como:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `copy_to_proveedores` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.TIPO='P' THEN INSERT INTO proveedor VALUES(NEW.UsuarioID);
END IF;
END
```